# osCommerce custom PHP page

Tags: php, oscommerce

One of my client has an old osCommerce website and while working on it I have to implement what I would call "custom php page", i.e. a page which query a MySQL table, not related to osCommerce, and list the result. I'm not sure of the version, this trick I have seen a lot didn't gave me any result : http://www.clubosc.com/how-to-know-what-version-of-oscommerce-you-are-using.html . And I'm having a hard time doing this seemingly simple task, since osCommerce doesn't allow any php code in the page creation, and I didn't find any module  giving me this possibility (not that it is easy to search in this mess : http://addons.oscommerce.com/). At this point I figured it would be easier to just hack'n slash through the code and come up with a custom page :

I copied the index.php (the entry point in the application) :

```
<?php
require('includes/application_top.php');

if(!$smarty->is_cached($sContentPage, $sCachingGroup)) {
  //we switch on the content recognition
  require('includes/pages/' . $sContentClass . '.php');
}

$smarty->display($sContentPage, $sCachingGroup);

require(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'application_bottom.php');
?>
```

Here I gave a specific value to $sContentClass (with or without the if makes no difference) and customize the corresponding PHP file so it show my custom content but also initialize the same variable than those other PHP file in the pages/ folder. But alas, all of this curious and dubious code simply return me the home page. So here I am, is there an osCommerce Guru around here, or would anyone has a better idea (oh and I also posted on the osCommerce forum, but I'm still waiting for a response...)? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, that I understand You correctly, but can't You just put Your code in this file and call it?

At the beginning I suggest leave requireing application_top and application_bootom, just put Your code here and let now if it displays Your content. Maybe in application_top is code that redirect to index.php if it not found... something specific somewhere :) It's hard to say without view of Your application_top.php